# Does wicket perform session serialization?

Tags: java, session, servlets, serialization, wicket

Suppose there is a custom session class which is extanded from `org.apache.wicket.authroles.authentication.AuthenticatedWebSession`. Technically `AuthenticatedWebSession` implements `Serializable` inteface.

But does it mean that wicket actually perform session serialization (may be in disk)? Or it is servlet container responsibility to hadnle such session serialization when it has not much memory?

Answer (score 3):

Wicket serializes only the pages with their components. It doesn't serialize the Session!

Here are some facts about Wicket that is good to understand:

- Almost all Wicket classes are serializable.
- Wicket allows clustering so it requires serializable sessions  (in this case, it is possible to use servlet container sharing, e.g. Tomcat shared session in Tomcat cluster).
- Wicket binds Servlet session whenever its needs to store a stateful page.
- by default Wicket uses serializer based on standard Java serialization that is used for pages. There are serializers based on Kryo and Fast-Serialize in WicketStuff project
- Wicket uses a SessionStore that's a special object that is responsible for storing/restoring Wicket's Session to/from the http session. The default implementation is HttpSessionStore, but you can implement your own (implement ISessionStore interface and add it into the Application singleton).
- Stateful Wicket components survive a single request, so it's a good ability to serialize them and store somewhere (on disk or share between servers over network).

Comment: I've made some corrections to your answer. Please let me know if you don't agree with any of them and we will discuss. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The Wicket Session object is stored as an attribute in the HttpSession.
It is job of the web container to replicate the http sessions, so it is its job to serialize the Session with all its attributes.

Wicket will serialize the Session **only** if it is kept as a non-transient reference in any of the application components. The application developer can use https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/297c4e51a925ef08c3ff903e4db26d2f910fe084/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/core/util/objects/checker/SessionChecker.java to prevent such errors.